# Most efficient way to check if point is inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using a MERN stack to code my website. A user searches for an area, an API call is then made to fetch a GeoJSON object (in particular a polygon) for that area.

I have a collection of points stored in MongoDB. What would be the most efficient way to check which points of the collection lie in the fetched polygon?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your polygon instances are assured to be enclosed shapes, draw a ray to the right of the point that may be inside a polygon. If it intersects the polygon edges an odd number of times, then it is inside the polygon

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Would it really be efficient? If there were say 100k points in the collection then that is a lot of lines that need drawing and checking through